# Division does not work in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'd like to calculate some information from a file but division does not work. If I change the `/` to a `+` or `-`, this calculation it doing right. Any ideas?

```
#!/bin/sh
    FILE=/tmp/stats

    for EMPTY in $(cat $FILE |sed '1!d'); do (echo "Empty Servers $EMPTY | Empty-Servers=$EMPTY;"); done
    for SERVERS in $(cat $FILE |sed '2!d'); do (echo "Total Servers $SERVERS | Total=$SERVERS;"); done

    PERCENT=$(((EMPTY / SERVERS)*100))
    echo $PERCENT
```

Comment: do you use `bash` (because of tag) or `sh` (first line of script)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Division does work, only that what the shell only deals with integers.

I think you'll either want to invoke something like `bc`, then you can do math however you like, or adapt to the implications of dealing with integers.

Example of what you could do instead: change your expression around such that you multiply `EMPTY` by `100` first, then divide by `SERVERS`. Ie, `$(((EMPTY * 100) / SERVERS))`.
(Of course, this may not be as precise as you would like, but it does not yield 0 as the result all the time.)

Answer (score 1):

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093871/how-can-i-do-division-with-variables-in-a-linux-shell), You need a `$` before `(EMPTY / SERVERS)` too. So your script should be as below:

```
#!/bin/sh
FILE=/tmp/stats

for EMPTY in $(cat $FILE |sed '1!d'); do (echo "Empty Servers $EMPTY | Empty-Servers=$EMPTY;"); done
for SERVERS in $(cat $FILE |sed '2!d'); do (echo "Total Servers $SERVERS | Total=$SERVERS;"); done

PERCENT=$(($((EMPTY / SERVERS))*100))
echo $PERCENT
```

And according to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30398014/divide-two-variables-in-bash), shell parsing is useful only for integer division so it's better to use `bc`.

Answer (score -1):

BC does it:

```
for PERCENT in $(echo "scale=3; ($EMPTY/$SERVERS)*100" | bc); do (echo "Percent Empty=$PERCENT;;");done
```